# Conversion formula for Heading of an object to match a value I have in int?

Tags: math, coordinate

I have a list of items heading that are all in INTEGER (yes the heading is 0 to 120 int) value but when I am reading them they are all in float, so in between there is a conversion being done that I am not aware of **(code not open so I can't check it myself but I need to update the xml and for that i must know how to convert it)**.

- What I wanted to find out here is
  what sort of conversion do I have to
  do in order to get out of the float a
  matching int for it as the examples
  OBJECT A and B.

First example is OBJECT A which has the floating heading 57 but has the int heading 109.
Second example is OBJECT B which has the floating heading 168 but has the int heading 26.

**The floating is 0 to 360 and the int is 0 to 120.**

Initially i was think about radians but there are 2 incosistences first is that OBJECT A is 57 having the int 109 so I would not be able to apply a converting formula to it I belive, second is that if I am not mistaken radians is up to 180.

I am really intrigued to understand why it has that integer representing a degree and how it is being converted to such...

PS: ***By the way I posted this in mathematics first before posting here but they requested it would be more suitable here.***

***UPDATE WITH MORE SAMPLES:***

```
 F    I
168   26
 57  109
180   30
165   25
 45  105
  0   90
318   99
348   86
240   50
204   38
345   85
```

F for Float
I for INT

Comment: Radians go up to 2*pi (or from -pi to +pi).

Comment: thanks for correcting that but even so it would not be limited from 0 to 120 so i belive it could be excluded.

Comment: post ONE MORE example. If there is a linear function, one more point is needed to verify the result

Comment: updated with a few more samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. Your coordinates systems are rotated 90 degrees, and 120 matches 360.

Your function is:

```
f[x_] := 3 Mod[x - 90, 120];
```

A plot

```
ListPlot[{kk, Table[{i[[1]], f[i[[1]]]}, {i, kk}]}, PlotMarkers -> {"X", "O"}]
```

[image]

All the points are OK, except the last one.

Comment: **First of all thanks for taking the time to help me out +1.** All the samples are in use and currently working. Dont know why the last one is wrong but it is not the only one with value above 180 or 300, I can post more samples if u want, float vary from 0 to 360 degrees.

Comment: @Prix You're welcome. Post them and lets see if we can find out what is happening there ...

Comment: @Prix I mean your last sample is the only one that does not work with the above formula

Comment: @belisarius added a few more samples, seems like that value is really wrong for converting from the float i have but all the others are 100% ok after you posted your formula I also got this `(float/3) - 30` if negative `result +120`

Comment: @Prix, yes. the only outlier is that one. Seems the formula is now correct.

Comment: @Prix That one was not trivial, and you had one bad point. Glad to help!

Comment: @belisarius yeah I know it was an unreasonable request... I wish I had a better knowledge about math or more time to learn it... once again thanks and indeed that one was a bad point :) all the other points I got above 200, 300 worked just fine.